# Using CIFilter, which image filters I should use for cloud, sunny moon light in iphone camera

Tags: ios, iphone, cifilter

I'm new to CIFilters in iOS, I have to implement some image filters in my project like Cloud, Sunny, Moon light, I don't know which filter I should chose for each of this one.

Below link is the apple official site for CIFilters: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004346-CH202-TPXREF101

I'll be very thankful to you if you guide me.

Thanks in Advance.
Ahmed Jabir

Comment: What, exactly, are "Cloud, Sunny, Moon light" in terms of effects? I think you're going to need to at least have sample images to show this, or we won't have any chance of answering this.

Answer (score 0):

You might try the CISunbeamsGenerator for the sun and the rays on the moon. As for the clouds, you might try creating some outlines for the clouds, then applying a CIGaussianBlur effect to them to make them look puffy.
Hope that helps!